# Wrong LevelOrder Traversal

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, queue, traversal

How can I fix this LevelOrder traversal?

```
public static void LevelOrder(TreeNode root){
        Queue <TreeNode> q = new LinkedList <>();
        TreeNode tmp=root;
        q.add(tmp);
        while (!q.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(q.remove().data + " ");
            if (tmp.left!=null) {
                q.add(tmp.left);
            }
            if (tmp.left!=null) {
                q.add(tmp.right);
            }
                tmp = q.peek();
        }

    }
```

Comment: why are you checking for temp.left!=null when adding tmp.right element in queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't just `remove()` from the queue without storing. Save it in a variable, as you need it to check left and right. You also didn't check if `root` is `null`. A possible fix to both issues:

```
public static void LevelOrder(TreeNode root) {
    Queue<TreeNode> q = new LinkedList<>();
    q.add(root);
    while (!q.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode tmp = q.remove();
        if (tmp == null) {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(tmp.data + " ");
        q.add(tmp.left);
        q.add(tmp.right);
    }
}
```

Instead of `remove()`, I suggest using `poll()`. The difference is that `remove()` will throw an exception if the queue is empty. But thanks to the loop condition we *know* that cannot happen. For more details on the various methods of LinkedList see the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: Couldn't we write it in a way that only use peek, remove and add functionalities of a queue? Thanks!

Comment: Also your answer works. I am willing to see if someone offers an answer that I can understand it much easier. Yours tend to be on the advanced end :)

Comment: I clarified a bit `poll` vs `remove`, see my updated post. There is no need for `peek` here, `remove/poll` and `add` are enough.